# System.currentTimeMillis() and daylight savings

Tags: java, android

I am wondering if System.currentTimeMillis() accounts for daylight savings on android.

Let's say I call
`x = System.currentTimeMillis();`

and then ten seconds later, the os switches the clock back an hour because of daylight savings.

And now I call
`y = System.currentTimeMillis();`

Which will be larger, `x` or `y`?

I ask this because if I manually change the clock, `x` is greater than `y`. So I wonder if daylight savings is accounted for when calculating the long value returned by `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Can't seem to find anything in the docs.

Comment: It is in the doc, actually: "the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC." from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()

Comment: I did see that, but by current time does it completely ignore daylight savings?  I think it would because it is independent of the Date system we use as humans, but I want to be sure.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: Also, read the doc again. epoch (January 1, 1970 UTC) is a fixed moment in time. The number of ms since that moment does not depend on anything except the number of ms since that moment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No, DST has no effect

> if System.currentTimeMillis() accounts for daylight savings

No.

[Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is irrelevant to [`System.currentTimeMillis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--).

The call to `System.currentTimeMillis` gives you a number of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`. No adjustments for Leap Second.

DST is defined, and redefined, on the whim of bored/uneducated/crazy politicians. DST applies only to their jurisdiction in one or more particular time zones.

DST cutovers are anomalies, disrupting [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) for a region’s citizens. But [space-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime) does not bend or warp with a DST cutover, time continues to flow smoothly. That flow of time is measured by `System.currentTimeMillis` without regard to machinations of local politicians.

## `Instant`

The `System.currentTimeMillis()` method is now obsolete. To get the current moment, use [`java.time.Instant.now`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#now()).

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

While a [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) can hold [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), in Java 9 and later you are likely to see the current moment captured in [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond). (Java 8 used [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond), before a new implementation of [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) in Java 9 and later.)

In contrast, the `System.currentTimeMillis` call is limited to milliseconds.

To get a count of milliseconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), 1970-01-01T00:00Z, call [`Instant::toEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli()). Of course, beware of data loss as any microseconds or nanoseconds are truncated from the result as milliseconds.

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = Instant.now().toEpochMilli() ;
```

`Instant` represents a moment in UTC. So Daylight Saving Time (DST) and similar anomalies caused by politicians have no effect.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ararua? Stumped the Google and me. As for rant, only about the silliness of passing laws telling everyone to wake up an hour early or an hour late with no rational justification.

Comment: Really?  I got several hits, but it could be due to my location.  When New Zealand introduced Daylight Savings in the mid-1970s, a farming community of about 100 people called Ararua rebelled.  For a number of years, they refused to participate and kept their clocks at the "non-daylight" time throughout summer.  There were even "time zone" maps published that showed Ararua time as a different time zone from New Zealand time.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Those are some smart folks in [Ararua NZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_New_Zealand#Daylight_saving_time_(DST)). Just silly to [rise early and milk cows in the dark](https://teara.govt.nz/en/photograph/6707/ararua-time).